# using a php variable inside of html using a jquery insertAfter

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I've got a php function that is something like this

```
function get_some_info() 
{

$location = other_function_that_returns_a_string();
 return <<<HTML
<script>

$("<h1> <?php echo $location ?> </h1>").insertAfter("header");

</script>
HTML;
}
```

but I can't get my variable to dynamically display.

I've also tried something like this

`$("<h1> <?php  $location = other_function_that_returns_a_string() echo $location?> </h1>").insertAfter("header");`

and it never displays anything dynamically. How can I get my variable to show up?

Comment: what if you hard code the `$location`? like `$("<h1> test </h1>").insertAfter("header");` - I doubt jquery selector will find something like this.

Comment: also the `<?php` _inside_ the HEREDOC will not do what you expect.

Comment: `<?php echo json_encode($location); ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you use the [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax.

You don't have to use `<?php` and `?>` inside that.

This will work fine:

```
$("<h1> $location </h1>").insertAfter("header");
```

Here is the code I tested in [PhpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    Header
</header>

<?php
function other_function_that_returns_a_string(){
    return "A string";
}

function get_some_info(){
    $location = other_function_that_returns_a_string();    // Will be "A string"
    return  <<<HTML
<script>
$("<h1> $location </h1>").insertAfter("header");
</script>
HTML;
}

echo get_some_info();

?>
```

Comment: Yes, so near, so far. Once we get the quircks of Heredoc everything rolls smoothly.

Comment: This is what I needed to see